# Can't transform data into a normal distribution

Tags: t-test, data-transformation, count-data

We have data on the counts of a certain disease in our city. We're trying to see if there's a difference between the male and female instances of it.

We have decided to t-test for this, but both of the male and female data are negatively-skewed. Because of that, we tried to normalize our data.

We tried all transformations that we can in R, and the only thing that got near to a normal distribution is by raising the data to 3. Everything else that we tried got more negatively-skewed.

Here is one of our original dat:
[image]
Skewness: -1.196408

[image]
Skewness: -1.028118

Here is the transformed data:
[image]
Skewness: -0.01734048

[image]
Skewness: 0.08755082

---

P values for

Original: 0.579

Transformed: 0.4802

I'm worried that the skewness indicates that this is near normal distribution, but I think the graph doesn't shape up to be a normally distributed one.

Can we use the t-test for this?

Comment: Some kind of power $> 1$ is indeed a standard transformation if the aim is to get closer to symmetry, but don't confuse lack of skewness with normality. My guess is that your P-values for a t-test with the original data are not that different from those for your transformed data. I am quite positive about transformations in general, but in this case I doubt that it's essential.

Comment: @NickCox this sounds like almost an answer.

Comment: @Tim Thanks, but a good answer would be possible if Raphael shares his data and/or his t test results. But  a minimum would be to show _both_ distributions, male and female.

Comment: @nickcox There really was really almost no difference with the p values of the original and transformed ones. What does this mean? Should we still proceed with this and present the results with the transformed data?

Comment: @nickcox I forgot to thank you in my last comment. I apologize if this really seems like a beginner comment. Again, thank you for helping me

Comment: "no difference" is an exaggeration, but the interpretation of a significance test  is the same. It might be salutary to focus on a confidence interval for the difference between the means. You could use bootstrapping if you were worried about the distributional assumptions.

Comment: Don't try "all transformations that we can". That suggests stabbing in the dark. There is a logic to transformations captured in the idea of a ladder of transformations. See e.g. http://onlinestatbook.com/2/transformations/tukey.html

Comment: You really should give more details & context. What is the individual counts? For city districts? ... With count data, you might be better of with a count distribution, like Poisson.  But only for a simple significance test, it might not matter ...

Comment: I have the same question as @kjetilbhalvorsen. What is on the x-axis in the graphs? Is it days counting from some start date and is the y-axis news cases on each of those days? If so, you should not do a t-test to compare those sets of data. Also, what numbers are you raising to the power of 3; from your graphs it looks like the numbers on the x-axis but when you say "the data" I think it should be the numbers on the y-axis.

Comment: @John L From e.g. $50^3 = 125000$ it is evident that time is being cubed. I don't see that the frequencies should be transformed at all. More information would help, but the question is otherwise clear enough: the aim is to compare distributions of times for males and females.